# How to cast an allocated memory block to an array addressable data type.

Tags: c#, pointers, casting, pinvoke

I am trying to Marshal some data from c# to a c library. The struct that I need to pass is just a collection of pointers... something like:

`struct sometype {
    type1* element1;
    type2** element2;
    type3** element3;
    type4* element4;
}`

Now... I've opted to forgo the attempt to copy all of these types into c# and marshal them as structures and decided to just fill a IntPtr array with the correct data in the correct order and pass it as a pointer. As you can see, in this setup I am passing a 4 position array of pointers with positions 1 and 2 being arrays of pointers themselves. It was simple enough and indeed does work when I marshal by fixing the IntPtr array...

```
fixed(IntPtr* ptr = structArray){
    InteropCall(ptr);
}
```

However, I soon realized that the c library is actually keeping a reference to the struct and after sometime, expectedly breaks when the array is moved or collected. So my solution was to allocate a block of memory using `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` and hold on to the reference throughout the time the c library needs that data.

So I run this:

`IntPtr* pointerArray = (IntPtr*)Marshal.AllocHGlobal (IntPtr.Size * 4);`

However, `pointerArray` always comes out as `IntPtr.Zero`... or i guess... just zero.

What am I doing wrong? Can I not cast a memory block into a pointer datatype? What if I wanted a `byte*` or `int*` so that I can operate on the memory block like an array?

Comment: Are you saying, that `Marshal.AllocHGlobal (IntPtr.Size * 4)` evaluates to zero? Try to write this exact line for testing purposes. I cannot believe 16 or 32 cannot be allocated.

Comment: @usr That is precisely what I am saying. Breakpointing and looking at pointerArray after the line is run gives me 0x000..0. It happens consistently too. Every single time without fail.

Comment: @HansPassant wouldn't the runtime throw an out of memory exception if that were the case? It doesn't happen but there is no way that the allocation really gave me address 0. I don't believe it.

Comment: Create a fresh console application with just that allocation line. I bet you quite an amount that it will not fail. Your system is very likely to have one more page of memory left... Probably, you have corrupted the heap (double-free? invalid memory writes?).

Comment: You're right. It does work. It works copying the exact line from my other application. It just doesn't work in my other application... odd...

Comment: You are likely to be inspecting `*pointerArray`.  A zero is entirely normal, although not guaranteed.  You are heading the wrong way, use plain IntPtr instead of IntPtr* and Marshal.StructureToPtr().

Comment: There's not enough information here. You do seem to be making life hard. Why do you reject structs? Why use unsafe?